# use ajax/js to update one of multiple select tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am running into a roadblock when attempting to use JavaScript to update a `<select>` tag on a page that I am creating. The issue I have is that this is a management style page, so there are multiple forms on one page, each one generated through PHP for an entry in a SQL database. For a better understanding of what I am talking about, here is some code from my project:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM tableA ";
$data = $PDOcon->query($query);
$rows = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $head = $row['head'];
    $cont = $row['content'];
    $app = $row['Product'];
    $category = $row['CatID'];

    Print "<form class='mgmt-ListView-Tall' action=\"#Anchor$id\" method=\"post\" width=\"60%\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"$id\" readonly />
    <label for='pHead'>Heading: </label>
    <input id='pHead' class='lbl-w25' name='pHead' value='$head' />
    <label for='pCont'>Content: </label>
    <input id='pCont' class='lbl-w20' name='pCont' value='$cont' />
    <label for='pProd' >Product: </label>
    <select id='pProd' name='pProd' class='pProd'>
        <option value='0'>Product 1</option>
        <option value='1'>Product 2</option>
    </select>
    <label for='pApp'>Application: </label>
    <select id='pApp' name='pApp' class='pApp'>
    </select>
    </select>
    <span><input class='mgmt-Button' id='editbtn' type=\"submit\" name='edit' value='Edit' /></span>
    </form>";
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.pProd').change(function(){
var string = this.value + ',' + '-1';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'scripts/get_app.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {get_option:string},
        success:function(data){
            document.getElementById('pApp').innerHTML=data; //This updates the select tag in the first form on the page, not the same form that the user was making changes in.
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I have a table (TableB) that contains a list of all applications linked with their product, and what I am attempting to do currently is set up the page so that if the user changes the product in the select field on one of the forms that is generated, the application select tag is updated through AJAX. I am able to get it to update the first form on the page using `document.getElementById`, but I need it to update the tag with that id that is in the same form as the select tag the user was modifying (example: user makes a change to the pProd tag in the 4th form, the pApp tag in the 4th form gets updated)

I have attempted to call `$(this).next(".pApp").innerHTML=data;`, but this does not appear to find the tag with the correct class. I have also tried using `closest()` and `sibling()` to no avail. I have also tried referencing both id, and class with the same results, and I have searched around and could not find any solution to a problem similar to this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: That is because `id` should be unique on the page. In your use case, you have multiple rows with the same id, and when ever you select that element, it will only get you the first element. Use `classes` instead and need to specify the correct context `this`

Comment: i have tried referencing by id and also class, and no dice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute needs to be unique:

> The **id** global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which **must be unique in the whole document**. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)</sup>

So one solution is to append `$id` to the id attributes of the select lists.

```
<label for='pProd$id' >Product: </label>
<select id='pProd$id' name='pProd' class='pProd'>
    <option value='0'>Product 1</option>
    <option value='1'>Product 2</option>
</select>
<label for='pApp$id'>Application: </label>
<select id='pApp$id' name='pApp' class='pApp'>
```

Then in the AJAX updater, parse out that value for $id using [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
$('.pProd').change(function(){
var id = this.id.replace('pProd','');
var string = this.value + ',' + '-1';
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {get_option:string},
    success:function(data){
        document.getElementById('pApp'+id).innerHTML=data; //This updates the select tag in the first form on the page, not the same form that the user was making changes in.
    }
```

See it demonstrated in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ey9g-ibv7).

Additionally, since jQuery is being used, the [id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) could be used to update the second select list:

```
success:function(data){
    $('#pApp'+id).html(data);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id</sub>

Comment: it appears that was what i needed, and works beautifully.